# Problems on Realm 'query between dates' when the target date is in bounds

Tags: java, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to fetch an object saved on Realm.

This object contains a date field.

The date of the object is 'Fri Mar 01 00:00:00 EST 2019'.

I am using a query 'between' the dates to try to get this object.

The dates used are 'Fri Mar 01 00:00:00 EST 2019' and 'Sun Mar 31 23:59:59 EDT 2019', what is basically the very beginning and end of that month.

The query returns empty, when I call 'findAll()' for that query. The weird thing is that sometimes it actually returns me something. And I am pretty sure that the object is store there, since when I call find all without any restriction of dates, the result is that object.

I read the documentation, and for what I understood, the expected behaviour is to have that object being returned in the result list.

```
val query = realm.where(MyDateObject::class.java)
query.between("date", dateReference.beginningOfMonth, dateReference.endOfMonth)
val list = query.findAll()
```

Comment: `EST` on one, and `EDT` on the other? Hmm....

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you're right, there's something weird with the second border, but still I imagine the question is valid, since it doesn't change anything in the first border, where is the object saved. I will try to put both in the same timezone, and see what happens.